# error "can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala". Using sbt and Scala Test,

Tags: scalatest

I got above error when i run 'test' under sbty.

environment: ScalaTest, sbt version 0.13.8

in the build.sbt file tried "scalaVersion := "2.10.4" and below dependency definition (both options):

//libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test"

I refreshed my sbt projects after the above changes.

the error still exists. can anybody give some lights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after playing around and helped by colleague, it turns out the version for scalaTest (ArtifactID)is incorrect, and now the working version is automatically get the right Scala Version (i.e. use GroupID %% artifactID %revision INSTEAD OF GroupID % artificatID %revision).

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest"  %% "scalatest"   % "2.2.4" % Test //note 2.2.2 works too
```

for more details see: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html